# cl.exe wrapper in Visual Studio 2008

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2008, compiler-construction, warnings, createprocess

I created a wrapper in C++ for the `cl.exe` (the Visual Studio compiler). To do this, I changed the `PATH` environment variable so that Visual Studio finds my `cl.exe` first. In my `cl.exe`, I then create a process that runs the real `cl.exe` with the parameters my `cl.exe` got.

The purpose of this is to filter the output from the real `cl.exe` to remove warnings that we can't do anything about. We want the "Detect 64-bit Probability Issues" on because it's great, but it spits out a warning.

Warning:

> cl : Command line warning D9035 : option 'Wp64' has been deprecated and will be removed in a future release

I have searched for days on how to remove this specific warning, it is **not** a warning that you can turn off with code or the options like normal warnings.

**Problem**: Visual Studios run my `cl.exe`, then my `cl.exe` runs the real `cl.exe`, but from then on my `cl.exe` doesn't receive the output anymore. I have tested this by making it call something other than the real `cl.exe` and my `cl.exe` has full control over the output...

Any output from either of the `cl.exe` files is displayed in the output box in Visual Studio, but my `cl.exe` no longer receives any of the output from the real `cl.exe`...

I am using a pipe to handle the output in my `cl.exe`, and it works with anything other than the real `cl.exe`.

Why doesn't my `cl.exe` manage the output? Does Visual Studio forget about my `cl.exe` and attach itself to the real one somehow?

Also, is there a solution other than creating a wrapper for the `cl.exe` to get rid of this warning?

Comment: Why do you want to get rid of those warnings so badly?

Comment: "I am using a pipe to handle the output in my cl.exe" You mean standard output?

Comment: This wrapper will be used my thousands of people if i can get it working. If there is one warning or a million, for each project it looks the same in the report.  Because of this warning each projct now shows up as having warnings.

Comment: I ment that I was handeling the output from the real cl.exe using a pipe. CreatePipe( ... ), startupInfo.hStdOutput = createdPipe, CreateProcess( ... startupinfo )

Comment: @Padawan Learner: There's at least a few reasons why Microsoft made it so that you can't turn off the `/Wp64` deprecation warning; one being that [there are situations where `/Wp64` produced bogus errors](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7171295/why-is-wp64-deprecated). Instead, you should run your code through the compiler set to target 64-bit systems. That's a better way to find 64-bit issues. `/Wp64` is way too buggy to be useful.

Comment: We realize that this isn't the best way to see possible 64bit errors but it is useful. Also there are other warnings that we want to remove...  I am starting to think that this is impossible with this approache.

Comment: Have you considered correcting the warnings instead?

Comment: The point of this projct is that the warnings are uncorrectable!

Comment: I don't follow this. 'We want the "Detect 64-bit Probability Issues" on because its great but it spits out a warning.' So you want to turn it *off* with your own cl.exe?

Answer (score 1):

I have figured it out.

This environment variable from visual studios is used somehow to signal the real cl.exe to send its output to visual studios.

VS_UNICODE_OUTPUT=4209

Clearing this allows my application to handle the output again.

Thanks for your help...!

Comment: Thank you! I really don't understand while this switch is marked deprecated, since it gives warnings you never get otherwise (but I can see the problems with templates). How is your wrapper working? Does it do what you expect?

Comment: It is working very well. It took me a while to iron out the subtleties of its functionality.  It only increases build times by approximatly 3% which is acceptable. It even works with incredibuild!  From the begining I never though this was possible.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are redirecting the "real" `cl.exe` `stdout`, but not `stderr`. And `stderr` is exactly where one would expect compiler warnings to go.