# Enabling C4311 on VS2010 x64 builds without use of /Wp64? (annoying D9035)

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-c++, 64-bit, compiler-warnings

We got hit by a bug that would have been found if C4311 had been active:

> ### [Compiler Warning (level 1) C4311](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4t91x2k5%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) [VS.100]
>
> 'variable' : pointer truncation from 'type' to 'type'
>
> This warning detects 64-bit portability issues. For example, if code is
> compiled on a 64-bit platform, the value of a pointer (64 bits) will be
> truncated if it is assigned to an int (32 bits).
>
> This warning **is only issued when `/Wp64`** is used. *[**so** true]*
> See [/Wp64](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yt4xw8fh%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) for more information.

Unfortunately it *seems* (see below for background) that to get C4311 I *must* provide `/Wp64`to my x64 build -- which results in `warning D9035: option 'Wp64' has been deprecated (...)` for every project in my solution (extremely annoying).

So **is there a way to** either:

- **Enable C4311 without `/Wp64` on VS2010?**
- or silence `D9035`?

---

## Background

The MSDN docs for `/Wp64` seem to be [totally off for VS2010](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yt4xw8fh%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) in that `C4311` is only *ever* active if you specify `/Wp64` *in the x64(!!) build*.

> ### [/Wp64 (Detect 64-Bit Portability Issues)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yt4xw8fh%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) [VS.100]
>
> By default, the /Wp64 compiler option is off in the Visual C++ 32-bit compiler and **on** in the Visual C++ 64-bit compiler. *[seem to be **wrong**]*
>
> ... Instead of using this option and keyword to detect 64-bit portability issues, use a Visual C++ compiler that targets a 64-bit platform. ... *[nopes, doesn't work for me]*
>
> ... you can just disable /Wp64 in your 32-bit compilations because the 64-bit compiler will detect all issues. ... *[I'm fine with disabling for Win32, but the x64 compiler just **won't** catch any C42311 without me telling him `/Wp64`]*

Another user confirms this [@Why is /Wp64 deprecated?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14818925/321013):

> /Wp64 on 64-bit builds is extremely useful. The documentation (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/yt4xw8fh.aspx) claims that it is on by default in 64-bit builds, but this is not true. Compiler warnings C4311 and C4312 are only emitted if /Wp64 is explicitly set. Those two warnings indicate when a 32-bit value is put into a pointer, or vice-versa.

---

Note on VS2015:

- There is no `/Wp64` option anymore, it's been removed, not only deprecated.
- The behavior is finally as expected - C4311 (e.g.) shown in 64bit build / not shown in 32bit build.

Comment: MSDN post: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/b037e961-9b03-4ebe-adf1-c0d37cf48d4f/enabling-c4311-on-vs2010-x64-builds-without-use-of-wp64

Comment: Not alone: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/f6ca2de2-be1e-48ba-b348-7b2261dc8692/x64-compiler-not-showing-wp64-warnings